# lwip example netconn_new is returning always NULL

Tags: lwip

iam trying to port the lwip example onto the RTOS, facing an issue like

`netconn_new(NETCONN_TCP);` always returning NULL. any idea ?

Thanks and Regards,
Madhu R

Answer (score 0):

this is fixed after changing the value of DEFAULT_TCP_RECVMBOX_SIZE in the lwipopts.h